# Sideways cell and normal cell don't align properly in tabularx

Tags: tables, tabularx, rotating, parbox

I'm trying to make a table where the first two columns should have their content rotated 90 degrees (sideways), the third normal (written horizontally), and the last one should have a `\multirow` with the content vertically centered. As you can see by this MWE, I have the problem that the second and third columns don't align properly. The third column should align to the top of the `\parbox` in the second one, which, however, is rotated.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx,multirow,tabularx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.5cm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2cm}|X|X|}
        \hline
        %\rowcolor{myblue}
        & Standard nach RLP & Stand der Kompetenzentwicklung & Konkretisierung \\
        \hline
        \rotatebox{90}{Inhaltsbezogene Standards} & \rotatebox{90}{\parbox{0.23\textheight}{\footnotesize Größen und Messen [L2]: Verwenden des Satzes von Pythagoras zur Berechnung von Streckenlängen in rechtwinkligen Dreiecken (auch an Körpern) (E, S. 43)}}& \underline{Deklarativ}: \newline Die SuS kennen \newline - die Hauptbegriffe \textit{Kathete} und \textit{Hypotenuse}, \newline - den Satz des Pythagoras \newline \underline{Prozedural}: \newline Sie können \newline - eine Seitenlänge in einem rechtwinkligen Dreieck berechnen, wenn die anderen zwei Seitenlängen gegeben sind & \multirow{2}{=}{Eine Probe} \\
        \cline{1-3}
        \rotatebox{90}{Prozessbezogene Standards} & \rotatebox{90}{\parbox{0.23\textheight}{{\footnotesize Probleme mathematisch lösen [K2]: Zusammenhänge erkennen und Lösungsstrategien auf ähnliche Sachverhalte übertragen (S. 19)}}} & & \\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

I have tried to play with the alignments of `\parbox` (t, b, c), but nothing seems to give me the correct result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to change the origin for the rotation:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx,multirow,tabularx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.5cm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2cm}|X|X|}
        \hline
        %\rowcolor{myblue}
        & Standard nach RLP & Stand der Kompetenzentwicklung & Konkretisierung \\
        \hline
        \rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{Inhaltsbezogene Standards}& \rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{\parbox{0.23\textheight}{\footnotesize Größen und Messen [L2]: Verwenden des Satzes von Pythagoras zur Berechnung von Streckenlängen in rechtwinkligen Dreiecken (auch an Körpern) (E, S. 43)}}& \underline{Deklarativ}: \newline Die SuS kennen \newline - die Hauptbegriffe \textit{Kathete} und \textit{Hypotenuse}, \newline - den Satz des Pythagoras \newline \underline{Prozedural}: \newline Sie können \newline - eine Seitenlänge in einem rechtwinkligen Dreieck berechnen, wenn die anderen zwei Seitenlängen gegeben sind & \multirow{2}{=}{Eine Probe} \\
        \cline{1-3}
        \rotatebox{90}{Prozessbezogene Standards} & \rotatebox{90}{\parbox{0.23\textheight}{{\footnotesize Probleme mathematisch lösen [K2]: Zusammenhänge erkennen und Lösungsstrategien auf ähnliche Sachverhalte übertragen (S. 19)}}} & & \\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you. I know I can play with the optional parameter <vmove> of `\multirow`, but is there a way to calculate the length I have to add (in this case negative) in order to get the text in the fourth  column to center vertically?